# Give root console access in php

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'd like to "embed" a shell console on a website that allows full root access to the shell. This is in an environment where the server is wiped every 5 minutes. Is there a way to do this in PHP? I can provide the shell a user/pass as well.

Comment: Did you at least tried to [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+shell)?

Comment: `exec()` and `proc_open()` are the functions that can work.

Comment: This is a really dangerous idea -- assuming you're setting it up as some sort of demonstration, there's a lot of nasty things someone can do with a server in 5 minutes. Sending a few thousand spam emails is one of them. :)

Comment: It's meant for developers so they can test their code in a short period of time. I'm disabling all mail functions.

Comment: That's nice that you're disabling mail functions. Since they have root access, how are you going to prevent them from re-enabling it?

Comment: It's impossible. Once a command is executed, it stays live for 2.5 minutes, and then kills itself. Once a command is run, you can't interact with the shell until it's over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of [web based shells](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+shell) written in PHP. They range from basic shells where you just input a command and hit submit, and get the output back, to sophisticated AJAX shells that let you run interactive terminal apps like IRC clients.

If you don't insist on the backend being PHP (the frontend can be), then [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) is a neat one.